# R graph: Issue with y-axis label

Tags: r, graph

I am very new to R. I am trying to learn. 
Due to some reason y-axis label is not showing up in the graph. Can anyone please help?

R version 3.0.1:
Script:

```
dose <- c(20, 30, 40, 45, 60)
drugA <- c(16, 20, 27, 40, 60)
drugB <- c(15, 18, 25, 31, 40)
opar <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
par(lwd=2, cex=1.5, font.lab=2)
plot(dose, drugA, type="b",
pch=15, lty=1, col="red", ylim=c(0, 60),
main="Drug A vs. Drug B",
xlab="Drug Dosage", ylab="Drug Response")
```

Above code shows the Drug Dosage but not showing Drug Response.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: This shows up fine for me.  Maybe my graphical device likes the margins better.  I use Cairo.  If you don't have it, install the package and then include `options(device="CairoWin")` when you start a session.  At the very least, your graphs will be prettier.

Comment: Works fine here (Win7_64, R3.0.1  .  What is your operating system, etc. ?   BTW, I recommend you put those `par` definitions inside your `plot` call so they don't affect your base environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running the code you provided and it worked perfectly in my installation of R.

Have you tried starting a new instance of R in which to run the code? It could be that in working you changed an environment variable or display device variable that is preventing the label from showing up.

If a plain restart doesn't work, run R with these arguments: R --no-restore-data --no-init-file

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and y-label came out just fine. Try starting a new rsession with:

```
R --no-restore-data --no-init-file
```

And plot again, could be something in your session which is causing trouble.